locale-gen not mutlti-threaded
I noticed that locale-gen is not multi-threaded, and is quite slow when it runs.
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done

Why does it not do a locale per thread?

I’m voting to close this question because the question why something doesn't do X often has no answer other than: because nobody bothered to implement it. Those interest in said behaviour should instead volunteer a patch that implements it.

@muru but it could also be that I am missing a config options somewhere, or a --threaded flag somewhere.

That's not what you're asking in the question, but even so, here's the manpage: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oracular/en/man8/locale-gen.8.html which lists a grand total of one (1) option, and doesn't relate to threading.
